# how we can align css boxes horizontally in IE

Tags: html, css

I need to alingn three css boxes horizontally in my web page.
I tried to do it using webkit and mozilla box orient and align properties.

```
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;
```

This code works well in Mozilla Firefox But not working in IE. I need the method for alligning boxes horizontally. Code must support all web browsers.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: CSS3 doesn't work on IE without javascript

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Use div like http://jsfiddle.net/eu9vr/

Comment: i used the same way to design boxes.It won't work in IE tell me some other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that is supported by all web browsers is something we all wish for :3

So far, most of the major browsers have started to implement *some* of the CSS3 features, and to be more specific, IE have yet to implement the box-orient feature, so you can't really get any support for that across all the major web browsers. As a suggestion, you should only consider using CSS3 if you're working on a progressive site with responsive design. I suggest using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to help you if that's what you wanna do.

Otherwise, you should stick with the tried and true methods, such as `inline` and `float` or *maybe* a table layout.

---

I've sampled some screenshots of an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCKmD/) for you, using [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) as a benchmark tool, to see how the different solutions look. The JSFiddle example includes

- `box-orient: horizontal;`
- `float: left;`
- `display: inline-block;`
- table layout

I only took browsershots of the fairly recent versions, but you can be more extensive with the comparisons on your own.

Anyway, [here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCKmD/) and here are the screenshots
[image: comparisons]

As you can see, the method(s) that seem to be supported by all major browsers and many of their versions are `float` and `inline-block`. Tables also work, but I recommend only using tables when you've got data to show, it's not really meant for design and layout.

<sub>Note that the only difference between IE8 and IE9 is the background-color because I use the `:nth-child()` pseudo, so there really isn't any actual difference. And IE7 doesn't know what `inline-block` is, so if you have a progressive site, just change that to `inline`.</sub>

These are the only solutions (that I know of) that will align boxes horizontally for you.